# Windows 7 64-bit: icon does not appear on taskbar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, icons, opera

I have installed the Opera browser on my Windows 7 64-bit.

since it is my main browser, I pinned it to the taskbar. however the opera icon does not appear, instead the default Windows icon is show. I even tried changing the icon to another one and unpinning and repinning, but still that default Windows file icon remains.

what could I do to show the icon?

Comment: Is it only Opera? Do you have same problem with other app icons?

Comment: for the moment it is only opera. other applications work fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem with a CCleaner icon. It would be pinned, but be the blank unknown application icon. I just removed it and tried again. Worked second time. Don't know why!

Comment: thanks good idea! however it didnt help in my situation!

Comment: It's possible that I had updated CCleaner before the second attempt. Have you tried updating or uninstalling and reinstalling Opera?

Comment: reinstalling helped.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to Rebuild the Icon Cache in Windows 7

**Information**

> If one or more of your icons are not
>   displaying correctly, or that your
>   icon cache is corrupted, then you
>   might consider rebuilding the icon
>   cache to reset and reload the icon
>   images into the icon cache.

**Note**
This will not help with any of the following icon issues:

> 1-A shortcut's icon that is not displayed properly due to the source
>   of the shortcut being moved or deleted. You may need to recreate a
>   new shortcut directly from the source
>   (ex: program's exe) file to replace it
>   instead.
>      2- All icons for a specific file extension display the wrong icon. This
>   may be do to setting the wrong
>   association for what program to open
>   the file extension instead.   You can
>   restore the default file extension's
>   associations to fix this icon instead.

If you have check that the source icon is not corrupted use this solution:
**[Windows 7 - Icon Cache - Rebuild](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/49819-icon-cache-rebuild.html)** *from the SevenForum tutorials*

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution posted at [a Microsoft forum](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7desktop/thread/fede67d8-0234-48c6-aa71-5a1503d6eaa0/):

1. First phase

   1. Click Start
   2. Right-click on Programs in the Start menu
   3. Select *Properties ⇨ Shortcut tab ⇨ Change Icon ⇨ Browse*
   4. Navigate to the `.exe` file for this program and select it
   5. Select an appropriate icon from options shown (if you get a message saying only an administrator can do this, click continue to apply the change.)
2. Second phase

   1. Start a session of the application
   2. While it is running, right-click the taskbar button
   3. Select *Unpin this program*
   4. Right-click again (shows icon now because it represents the running app, not the shortcut)
   5. Select *Pin this program*

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by setting my 'Taskbar buttons' taskbar setting to anything but 'Always combine, hide labels' (the default)

Answer (score 0):

As you will see elsewhere rebuilding the icon cache may work.  For me, on Windows 7 64-bit, after installing Adobe Acrobat Reader DC, the icon for Opera suddenly became generic.  Restarting the computer, re-pinning Opera to task bar did not help.

As mentioned by Denja there is a solution in the SevenForums: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/49819-icon-cache-rebuild.html

To expand on that answer a little and protect against link rot, the SevenForum procedure involves running the following commands from a command prompt.

```
ie4uinit.exe -ClearIconCache
taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F
DEL "%localappdata%\IconCache.db" /A
shutdown /r /f /t 00
```

I copied the above command into notepad (you don't need to save it), closed all other programs, ran an elevated command prompt (typed 'cmd' in start menu search and then right-clicked `cmd.exe` and chose 'Run as administrator'). The I copied and pasted the commands one at a time and ran them.

When executing the last command the computer will restart immediately so make sure you've saved anything you need before running the above commands.

Basically the above deletes the IconCache.db file which will automatically get rebuilt when windows starts.  When you restart, your icons will be blank but will slowly repopulate within 10-20 seconds or so.

This fixed the opera icon issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just Do this simple trick and it will work.

change momentarily the screen color depth to 16 bits and when Windows asks you whether you want to keep the changes or not, click "No" to restore the original settings.

Then Pin the Icon, it should work